# What percentage of digg / reddit / hacker news users contribute to the site?

Tags: social-media

I am trying to get a rough idea on the critical mass of users necessary to make a digg clone work.  To do that I need an estimate on what percentage of users submit links, post comments and vote.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

The best I can manage to find with reddit stats are:

Almost [14 million unique visitors, 1 billion(!) page views](http://blog.reddit.com/2011/02/reddit-billions-served.html) from googles monthly analystics.

Then looking at the [top scoring monthly reddit pages](http://www.reddit.com/top/?t=month) the top voted item has 3723 votes, the largest number of comments I can find on a single item were around 2500*

Personally, I think if any site manages 75/25 lurking/participation @tadamson mentions your doing quite well, from my experience the stats are closer to 80/20, 90/10 or even as low as 95/5.

*This was posted 2nd March, so its possible this is just for the month of March in which case you might want to check at the end of the month for a more rounder picture.

Answer (score 0):

Not a legitimate or verifiable answer, since I'm just going by sites I've worked on, but for public user-driven sites, it's generally around 75% lurkers and 25% active participants. That's for submissions and comments only. Voting would probably be the opposite, assuming it's just a simple one-click thing and user registration isn't a big hassle.

I don't think any of the above sites have published those stats. StackExchange is pretty open with their [data](http://data.stackexchange.com/) and you might be able to glean something from that, but SE is obviously a little different than a digg clone.